# Trigger in PostGIS that deletes or updates a feature based on location

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, trigger

In PostGIS I have two tables: closures (id, name, endpoint, geom)  and chambers (id, name, geom). A closure must always be placed in a chamber for which it will take the chambers name it has been placed into and insert it in the closures's endpoint field. The following piece of code works as expected;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_schema.closures_endpoint_name_trigger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

    BEGIN 
         IF (SELECT count(a.name) FROM the_schema.chambers a WHERE st_within(NEW.geom, st_buffer(a.geom,0.1))) > 0
         THEN NEW.endpoint =(SELECT a.name as name FROM the_schema.chambers a WHERE st_within(NEW.geom, st_buffer(a.geom,0.1)) LIMIT 1);
         ELSEIF (SELECT count(a.name) FROM the_schema.chambers a WHERE st_within(NEW.geom, st_buffer(a.geom,0.1))) = 0
         THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'YOU NEED TO PLACE A CLOSURE IN A CHAMBER';
         ELSEIF NEW.endpoint is null
         THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'YOU MUST SAVE CHAMBERS LAYER FIRST OR MAKE SURE CLOSURES SNAP THEIR ENDPOINT';
         END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;

$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER closures_endpoint_name_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON the_schema.closures
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE the_schema.closures_endpoint_name_trigger_function();
```

But I have realised that if I delete a chamber or change it's placement, the closure will still have the endpoint of the chamber I just deleted or moved. Is there a way to create a trigger that deletes the closure or set to null the endpoint value (so that it raises an exception) after having removed or moved a chamber? I want to do it with a trigger as it is based on location so a 'on delete cascade' statement referencing the two related fields do not work for me. Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Comment: A `FOREIGN KEY endpoint REFERENCES chambers ("name") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` should actually work pretty well? Except, of course, `"name"` is not unique. Otherwise an `ON DELETE` trigger on `chambers` doing a `DELETE FROM closures WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, OLD.geom) AND endpoint = OLD."name"` - to include an intersection check

Comment: Thank you geozelot I created a trigger as you said and works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, just add an `AFTER DELETE` trigger with the intended logic, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_schema.chamber_closure_cascade_trigger_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        DELETE
        FROM    the_schema.closures AS c
        WHERE   ST_DWithin(c.geom, OLD.geom, 0.1)
        -- AND   c.endpoint = OLD."name"
        ;

        RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $$
;

CREATE TRIGGER chamber_closure_cascade_trigger
    AFTER DELETE
    ON the_schema.chambers
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE the_schema.chamber_closure_cascade_trigger_function()
;
```

---

Note the usage of the index optimized `ST_DWithin` call instead of the `ST_Within(ST_Buffer)` construct. In general, your `UPSERT` trigger is rather convoluted and inefficient - consider rewriting it to sth. like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_schema.closures_endpoint_name_trigger_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT  c."name"
        FROM    the_schema.chambers AS c
        WHERE   ST_DWithin(c.geom, NEW.geom, 0.1)
        LIMIT   1
        INTO    NEW.endpoint
        ;

        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'YOU NEED TO PLACE A CLOSURE WITHIN A CHAMBER';
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
;

CREATE TRIGGER closures_endpoint_name_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON the_schema.closures
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE the_schema.closures_endpoint_name_trigger_function()
;
```

This omits the somewhat awkward implementation in your code for when an `UPDATE` takes place and `NEW.endpoint` is `NULL`, and simply tries to find the matching `chamber` as for an `ÌNSERT`.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. I will rewrite my code so it is more efficient.